# Merge list of uneven dataframes by rownames

Tags: r

I have several dataframes in a list, which i want to merge into one big dataframe. The actual list contains several thouands of this dataframes and i am therefore looking for a preferably efficient solution.

The list looks similar to this:

```
v <- data.frame(answer = c(1,1,1))
rownames(v) <- c("A","B","C")
w <- data.frame(answer = c(1,0,0))
rownames(w) <- c("A","B","D")
x <- data.frame(answer = c(1,1,1))
rownames(x) <- c("A","B","C")
y <- data.frame(answer = c(0,0,0))
rownames(y) <- c("A","C","D")
z <- data.frame(answer = c(0,0,0,1))
rownames(z) <- c("A","B","C","D")
l <- list(v,w,x,y,z)
names(l) <- c("V","W","X","Y","Z")
```

The final output should look like this:

```
    v    W    X    Y    Z
A   1    1    1    0    0
B   1    0    1    NA   0
C   1    NA   1    0    0
D   NA   0    NA   0    1
```

**What i have tried already** (feel free to ignore this part, if you already have a working solution)

```
  df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=length(l), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, l)
```

and

```
df<- rbindlist(l) (from library("data.frame"))
```

Those all loose the information contained in the rownames and only seemed to  work if all dataframes have the same length and the same order.

The only one that kinda worked with my actual data was something along the lines of:

```
df<- suppressWarnings(Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = 
"answer", all = TRUE),l))
```

but i am not able to make it work with my example list and even when it worked it was extremly unefficiently and took ages once the list got longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a row names column and then do the join.  We loop through the `list` with `map`, create a row names column with `rownames_to_column` and `reduce` to a single dataset by doing a `full_join` `by` the row names and `rename` the column names if needed

```
library(tidyverse)
l %>% 
   map( ~ .x %>%
             rownames_to_column('rn')) %>%
   reduce(full_join, by = 'rn') %>%
   rename_at(2:6, ~ names(l))
#  rn  V  W  X  Y Z
#1  A  1  1  1  0 0
#2  B  1  0  1 NA 0
#3  C  1 NA  1  0 0
#4  D NA  0 NA  0 1
```

---

Or another option is to `bind_rows` and then `spread`

```
l %>%
  map(rownames_to_column, 'rn') %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
  spread(grp, answer)
#  rn  V  W  X  Y Z
#1  A  1  1  1  0 0
#2  B  1  0  1 NA 0
#3  C  1 NA  1  0 0
#4  D NA  0 NA  0 1
```

Comment: Having someone solve my problem with a one.liner in less time than it took me to write it down always makes me feel amazed and patethic at the same time...
It does indeed work.

 Is there any way, i could get a very brief descritption of how it works? I haven't used tidyverse before and the code looks very criptyc to me.

Comment: I was writing something very similar, using `imap` : `imap(l,~rownames_to_column(setNames(.x,.y))) %>%
  reduce(full_join)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a base R solution using `merge` and `Reduce`:

```
df <- Reduce(
    function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "id", all = T),
    lapply(l, function(x) { x$id <- rownames(x); x }))
colnames(df) <- c("id", names(l))
#  id  V  W  X  Y Z
#1  A  1  1  1  0 0
#2  B  1  0  1 NA 0
#3  C  1 NA  1  0 0
#4  D NA  0 NA  0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this using something similar to what kind of already worked for you is to first declare the rownames as a variable, then rename the columns of your data frames to match their names in the list, and then merge.

```
df_l <- l %>% Map(setNames, ., names(.)) %>%
  map(~mutate(., r=rownames(.))) %>% 
  Reduce(function(dtf1,dtf2) full_join(dtf1,dtf2,by="r"), .)

rownames(df_l) <- df_l$r
df_l$r <- NULL
```

To be honest, I'm not sure it is efficient though, and like you said it will probably take long as the list grows.